# How do I load a JavaScript file with react-router-dom and React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When the page fist loads, the script is called and the page displays correctly. When I switch pages routes using react-router, the javascript is not rerun so I end up with an empty div. Here' my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const ServiceCard = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/juju-cards-v1.7.2.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.card}>
      <div>
        <h4 className={classes.headerTitle}>{props.title}</h4>
        <p className={classes.headerDescription}>{props.description}</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div
          className="juju-card"
          data-id="~omnivector/bundle/elasticsearch-non-uniform-2"
          data-dd
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ServiceCard;
```

I found a solution using class based components but I trying to avoid them for this project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you appending a script whenever any props change? Seems like something you want to attach once, preferably just in the html file, not for every service card for every prop change

Comment: The script creates a card that links to the JuJu store. Adding the script to the html file only runs it when the page loads the first time. Maybe I dont understand how these things work well enough? This page (https://www.omnivector.solutions/elasticsearch) shows the cards being rendered in an iframe. I'm trying to recreate that page using react.

Answer (score 0):

I see this code should work only for the first time as next time onwards your props are not going to change and useEffect hook will not run. 
You can try removing props from the dependency and just use[].
And make sure script is not injected each and every time.

If that does not work , you should use dymanic imports for the resources which is promise based solution.

Comment: Removing props from the dependency doesn't fix it. I'll look into dynamic imports. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your props are not changing on changing routes. You should wrap your component with `withRouter()` HOF and use `props.location.pathname` instead of `props` to check for route changes in your `useEffect` hook.